# Writing rule in Drools - conditional sum

Tags: drools, rule-engine, accumulate

I am stuck in writing a rule for a particular problem statement. 
I have an excel file having columns id, specialty,salary. Specialty can take values such as "oncology","urology" etc. I have to calculate total salary corresponding to each specialty. 
There are two ways of doing this.

First:

```
rule "Total salary of Oncology" 

no-loop
lock-on-active
salience 100
    when

    $m : Masterclass( $id : phyid , $p : p,spec=="Oncology")
     not Masterclass( spec=="Oncology", phyid < $id)
    $total : Number() from accumulate ( Masterclass(  $salary : salary ,spec=="Oncology") ,
                init( double total =0;), 
                action(total+=$salary;),
                result(  new Double (total)))
    then
    System.out.println($m.getSpec());
    System.out.println("Total target pay is : " + $total + " of specialty : "+ $m.getSpec());
    retract($m);
end
```

And similarly for other specialties.
This rule works fine.

Second:
Write only a single rule which reads the value of specialty and then sums up the salaries corresponding to it. 
I tried to implement this but didn't succeed.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "Read" from where? Your keyboard? A file? A whiteboard ;-) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far from perfect. But note that you don't have to insert some specific string. Running the rule without a string to match will produce the accumulated sums for all specialities anyway.

And you should wrap the String into a Java class - I was just too lazy to invent a proper Java class with one field.

```
rule "trigger read"
when
  not String()
then
  String s = read_any_way_you_want();
  insert( s );
end;

rule "Total salary of something" 
when
  $spec: String()
  $m : Masterclass( $id: phyid , spec == $spec)
  not Masterclass( spec == $spec, phyid < $id)
  $total : Number() from
     accumulate ( Masterclass($salary: salary, spec == $spec) ,
            init( double total =0;), 
            action(total+=$salary;),
            result( new Double (total)))
then
  System.out.println($m.getSpec());
  System.out.println("Total target pay is : " + $total + 
                     " o specialty : "+ $m.getSpec());
  retract($spec);
end
```